# What should happen after a successful submit on an admin content creation page?

Tags: forms, submit, administration, redirect

I am creating a website in which its admins have elevated privileges to create articles and other content through forms. Using the article creation scenario, what behavior would be most ideal for an admin upon successful form submission? The scenarios might be:

1. Clear all inputs and give the admin the opportunity to create another article.
2. Disable the submit button.
3. Redirect the admin to the live article view page if they chose to "publish" it on submission. What if they didn't publish it?
4. Bring them back to the main admin page.

Is there any clear option here that I should go with? In any case if the admin is not redirected there will be a success message dialog. There are a couple similar posts on UX but none specific to admins that I can find. Thanks in advance!

Comment: how likely are they to immediately create another article?

Comment: Is there a view in the site that shows all articles?

Comment: @dennislees Yes there is a view that shows all articles.

Comment: @Midas Maybe 25% of the time they would add another article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the most likely scenario? 
Do admins commonly add several articles? - -  create and add another 
 Do the articles have formatting they have to review? - -  create and review

Otherwise send them back to where they come from.

In some cases you need them to edit what they just created,  like add some data,  then i send them to the edit page.

You can also add several buttons with clear labels.

Comment: This about sums it up I suppose. I will have to do more research and find the answer as you explained. Thanks.